# проксирование на apache

Tags: linux, apache, nginx, прокси

Собственно, вопрос в следующем: имеется сервер на виртуальной машине на ubuntu. сейчас он настроен так: front - nginx, далее проксируется на fpm. есть apache, который висит на 8080 порту. Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы работало одновременно проксирование и на apache и на fpm?

Comment: в целом пока не разобрался с данной ситуацией увидел 2 выхода: -отбросить nginx и использовать только apache. запустить 2 серв, на котором оформить проксирование. Я может вообще глупые вещи спрашиваю? вместо минусов к вопросы хотелось бы увидеть конструктивную критику.